# How to redirect from Facebook browser to Android market?

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, redirect, google-play

In my site, there is a link that once clicked, goes through a series of redirect that eventually should go to the app market.

The final redirect URL is something like:

```
market://details?id=APP-IDENTIFIER
```

And it is started by calling:

```
window.open(url,"_blank")
```

On Android, when clicking in a regular browser - all works well.
When opening the page in the **facebook browser**, the redirect fails with the following message:

> The webpage could not be loaded as" net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

I am aware that any app may block custom scheme access, but is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem is oddly solved by starting the redirect chain by calling:

`window.open(url,"_top")`

instead of *_blank.

Comment: By the way, it's happening only on newer devices.
I suspect it's a chromium thing.

Answer (score 2):

don't user the `market://` identifier, but the actual play store link `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<APP-ID>`

- if the app is not blocking, the Play Store will open with no issues
- if the app is blocking launching of apps, at least you'll show the Play Store page.

Comment: If Facebook is blocking, it will open on Facebook internal thing. If not, of will open on market. You can do a simple test and find out

Comment: Opening a link to google play in facebook browser (unlike in chrome, by the way), opens the web version of the play store inside the browser. I will do this as a last resort, but I want to redirect him to the market app.

Comment: You can't force applications to do what you. If Facebook won't open, it won't open.

Comment: If you use window.open(url,"_top") - it does :)

Comment: I would argue that it's not forcing to do what u want, but you found the proper way to do what u want. Anyway, happy it works.